# Display select fields using conditional statements in JS

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am designing a self-service site for people with problems accessing a secure website. I want it to generate drop downs with questions about their situation based on the answers to each previous drop down box. I am trying to use `JS` and `conditional statements` to accomplish this. I am not a programmer but I understand it enough to reverse engineer it. Here's what I have so far.

```
<select id="location" name="location" onclick='test()'>
  <option value="0">Is this a personal computer or government computer?</option>
  <option value="home">Personal</option>
  <option value="gfe">Government</option>
</select>

<select id="home" name="home" style="display: none" onclick='test()'>
  <option value="0">Do you have a CAC?</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<select id="multi-cac" name="multi-cac" style="display: none" onclick='test()'>
  <option value="0">How many CACs do you have?</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">More than 1</option>
</select>

<select id="gfe" name="gfe" style="display: none" onclick='test()'>
  <option value="0">Is this a shared computer?</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<select id="shared" name="shared" style="display: none" onclick='test()'>
  <option value="0">Can other people access OWA on it?</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<select id="overseas" name="overseas" style="display: none" onclick='test()'>
  <option value="0">Have you recently returned from an overseas deployment?</option>
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="2">No</option>
</select>

<div id="overseas-answer" style="display: none" onclick='test()'>
  Please visit <a href="https://www.dmdc.osd.mil/milconnect">Milconnect</a> and update your profile. Please wait 24 hours and try accessing your email again. If this does not work, please contact the help desk  
</div>    

function test() {
  if (document.getElementById('location').value == 'home') {
    document.getElementById('home').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('home').style.display = 'none';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('location').value == 'gfe') {
    document.getElementById('gfe').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('gfe').style.display = 'none';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('gfe').value == '1') {
    document.getElementById('shared').style.display = 'block';
  }  else {
    document.getElementById('shared').style.display = 'none';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('shared').value == '1') {
    document.getElementById('overseas').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('overseas').style.display = 'none';
  }

  if (document.getElementById('overseas').value == '1') {
    document.getElementById('overseas-answer').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('overseas-answer').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Where I'm getting stuck is I can't figure out how to write the code to say something like "if value for gfe is 1 show shared. if value of gfe is 2 show multicac." when I try to write this it either does not work or it shows drop downs I don't want the user to see yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/JKqWf/341/ Here is a link to it.

Am I going at this wrong? Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For all of the `<select>` change `onclick` to `onchange`.  You might also want to pass in the id and value `onchange="test(this.id, this.value);"` into `function test(id, value){...}` So this way you know what was passed and by `<select>` and you don't have to go down the line making a bunch of `document.getElementById()` calls.

Comment: the first part I understand. change onclick to onchange. The second part I don't understand. Will there be multiple functions instead of of just one then, corresponding to each select or div item?

Comment: Multiple `functions` are easier to maintain and debug. You can make `test` your main `function` that takes in the `id` of the `select` and the `value` as I mentioned in my earlier comment.  `test` would check what `id` was passed in and call a `function` that handles the logic for that `select`'s `value`s.

Comment: @user3693135: So long code can turn SO users lazy about reading it and helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have with the way you have it is...  When `test` is called it goes down and hits every `if` and tries to get the value for each drop down displaying or not.  You want to only worry about the `select` that was changed.

For each of the selects do this...

`<select id="location" name="location" onchange='test(this.id, this.value)'>`

Then for `test`...

```
function test(id, val){
  if(id == "location"){
    handleLocationValues(val);
  }
  else if(id == "home"){
    handleHomeValues(val);
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

Then you can make your "handle values" `functions` like this...

```
function handleLocationValue(val){
  if(val == "home"){
    // write code to show the home drop down..
  }
  else if{val == "gfe"){
    // write code to show the gfe drop down...
  }
  ...
}
```

You also are going to want to write logic if the user goes back up and changes one of the previous `select` that you hide all of the visible `selects` below it.

I noticed that in your fiddle you have jquery selected as one of the frameworks.  If you are pulling that in then I would suggest looking into using it as it could make this so much easier.  It will also get you to not use inline events and styles.

I hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: I made the updates that you said and it still isn't working so I looked into jquery. I don't know quite what that is but I found that you can use lists instead of select boxes to achieve essentially the same effect without having to write logic for if the user changes something. I'm going to write it all out and post back here once I got it because I know I'm going to have more questions. I'm not a programmer ;) I'm a desktop support guy trying to make my life a little easier. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: I found a jquery that will do it. the code is to do it goes like this: `$('li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
    ullist.slideToggle();
}); `and that works but it all the fields are expanded by default. I want them to be collapsed by default and don't know how to do that. Also I want it to collapse children if it collapses a parent item. I think this will be my last question regarding getting this working. :)

Comment: To hide everything at the start you can use css.  To hide the siblings when you close a parent you pass in a function into `.hide('fast')` like so... `.hide('fast', function(){...})` in that function you find all `ul` and `.hide()` them. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pf6Wv/56/)

Comment: Thanks a ton. I'm putting the site together now. I got that all the list info goes in the body. I got that the css goes in the head unbetween style tags. Where does the jquery script go and how do I specify that I'm using jquery? I've only ever done basic html and rarely so I'm sorry that I have such poor fundamental knowledge.

Comment: Actually nevermind. I got it! Thanks a ton. You have helped me tremendously.